# Nodemailer: mail command failed

Tags: next.js, nodemailer

I keep getting the error:

```
Mail command failed: 554 5.7.8 User [contact@example.com] not authorized to send on behalf of <test@test.com>
```

This is my code:

*api/contact.js*

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer"

export default async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, phone, message} = req.body;
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "send.one.com",
        port: 465,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user:'contact@example.com',
            pass: 'password'
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    try {
        await transporter.sendMail({
            from: {
                name: req.body.name,
                address: email
            },
            to: 'contact@example',
            subject: `Contact form submission from ${name}`,
            html: `<p>You have received a contact form submission</p><br>
            <p><strong>Email: </strong> ${email}</p><br>
            <p><strong>Phone: </strong> ${phone}</p><br>
            <p><strong>Message: </strong> ${message}</p><br>`
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({error: error.message || error.toString() })
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ error: ""});
};
```

*contact.js:*

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Contact() {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        message: ''
    })

    const [form, setForm] = useState('')

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setInputs((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        }))
    }

    const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        if (inputs.name && inputs.email && inputs.phone && inputs.message) {
            setForm({ state: 'loading' })
            try {
                const res = await fetch(`api/contact`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(inputs)
                })

                const { error } = await res.json()

                if (error) {
                    setForm({
                        state: 'error',
                        message: error
                    })
                    return
                }

                setForm({
                    state: 'success',
                    message: 'Your message was sent successfully.'
                })
                setInputs({
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    phone: '',
                    message: ''
                })
            } catch (error) {
                setForm({
                    state: 'error',
                    message: 'Something went wrong.'
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

None of my Google searches seem to bear any fruit. Does it have something to do with my domain provider? I have tested my code with Gmail, and it works like a charm, but not with one.com.

I am open for suggestions. This error has had me stumbled for days now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're trying to send an email from an unauthorized source is because your **from** option is using data from the request. You wont be able to send an email from a source you aren't authorized to use. You should be sending from contact@example.com.

I'm not sure of the exact goal of the form, but consider redesigning the flow of the email service to send emails from your own source (contact@example.com) otherwise, you have to take the users email authorization credentials as input which can and will go south quickly.